# cd command not recognized by a systemd service script

Tags: debian, bash, systemd, shell

Hi run Debian OS and I have a shell script that runs sphinx search.
The script runs fine if I run it from terminal as below:

```
sh /home/myuser/sphinx/run_sphinx.sh
```

Here is the content of run_sphinx.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd bin/ || exit
./searchd -c ../../application/engine/config/sphinx_config_files/sphinx.conf
```

I created a service that runs when the server reboots.
The script is as below:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Description

[Service]
User=myuser
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser/
ExecStart=sh /home/myuser/sphinx/run_sphinx.sh
# optional items below
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run it  `sudo systemctl start run-sphinx-on-startup.service` It does not run as it gives an error:

```
/home/myuser/sphinx/run_sphinx.sh: 2: cd: can't cd to bin/
systemd[1]: run-sphinx-on-startup.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
systemd[1]: run-sphinx-on-startup.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Why is cd not recognized when run from systemd service as part of a shell script run by a command?
Any help please?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path for `cd`? It doesn't say that `cd` is not a command; it says `cd` cant change to `bin/`.

Answer (score 2):

It was indeed an absolute path issue so I just hard coded the path to the bin folder I have and it worked.